# How to auto-close date popup and hide div on selected change of element?

Tags: vue.js

1. Rent Date doesn't auto close. It’s getting error as below. I'm not sure it's inside of the Div. Getting below error.

   > "[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: 'TypeError: $refs.qDateProxy.hide is not a function'
2. Want to hide the `RentDate` when user select `Buy` from individual Book’s Select Option. How should I change it? There will be multiple books.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hiro-john/pen/GRRRNRK?editors=1010)

1. To auto close the date popup when user select on the date.
2. Hide 'RentDate' when user choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) or [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) for conditional hide show the `Book RentDate` on changes of boot type.

> The directive `v-if` is used to conditionally render a block. The block will only be rendered if the directive’s expression returns a truthy value.

```
<h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
```

> Another option for conditionally displaying an element is the `v-show` directive. The usage is largely the same:

```
<h1 v-show="ok">Hello!</h1>
```

And for this error `$refs.qDateProxy.hide`, you can create a method and inside of this method you can use like below

```
 onRentDateChange(){
    this.$refs.qDateProxy[0].hide()
 },
```

You can check here with working [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/JjjYGmE).

---

**EDIT**

As per OP's comment, I have updated [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/JjjYGmE). I have taken boolean variable inside of `this.$data.Books` array and used [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array for changing variable status.

```
onValueChange(val,id){
   let rec = this.$data.Books.find(({ID})=> ID==id);
   if(rec) rec.isRentShow = val == 'Rent';
},
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just check and realized that if I have multiple books, it doesn't reflect on that individual book itself.

E.g Book 1, I choose for Rent. I click on 'Add Book' and that 'Rent' field appear on Book 2 too. [link]https://i.ibb.co/WpWc5By/issue-001.png

If I change Book 2's status to 'Buy' the Rent_Date from Book 1 also disappear. [link]
https://i.ibb.co/QXk7W2s/issue-002.png

How can I fix that?

Comment: @latt I have updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/JjjYGmE). As per you comment, i have taken a variable inside of `Books` array and implement same logic inside of same method. Pleas check

Comment: can I ask you one more question? I want to auto-populate data for Vuetify. 

I have this set of  array. 

[{"ID":"1","Name":"JOHN DOE","Email":"JohnDoe@GMAIL.COM","Phone Number":"58656","Address":"Somewhere"}];

If anyone select, 'JOHN DOE' from the Name Dropdown, his details should be auto-populate to the respective fields which are 'Email, Phone & Address.'

My codepen is as below. 

https://codepen.io/hiro-john/pen/jOOwwza?editors=1010

Thanks in advance.